# How do I tell Windows 7 to trust a particular network location?

Tags: windows-7, networking, trust

How do I tell Windows 7 to trust a particular network location?  I'm not sure how to elaborate from the title of the question!

I keep getting popups aka "this location is not trusted".

I've mapped a network location to a drive and I want to trust it 100%, how do I do that?

Answer (score 48):

Try this:

1. Start Menu > type 'Internet Options'.
2. Select the **Security tab**
3. Select **Local intranet zone**, then click the **Sites** button, then click **Advanced** button
4. Enter `file://[computer name]`
5. Make sure '**Require server verification...**' is unticked

Comment: Should this change become active immediately or not until a restart of the Window-PC?

Comment: Where on client or on server?

Answer (score 6):

Controlpanel - network - internet options - local intranet.
Add site: fill ip.
Change "automaticly recognize local intranet locations"  to "trust all unc path's" (not exact naming, im to lazy to check it)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open **Control Panel** and select
   **Network and Sharing Center**
2. In the *Active Networks* section of
   the Window, select the network you
   want to trust
3. A new dialog shows
   requesting the new *Location* for
   this network Select **Home
   Network**.

Despite the misguiding name, Home Network is used for networks you trust. The names may be somewhat confusing an unintuitive to the task at hand. But here's an explanation:

Networks in Windows 7 are divided in two major groups; *Private* and *Public* groups. Private groups are split into two types of networks; *Home* and *Work* networks. Private groups are thus networks with a good deal of trust between computers. The Public group only offers the Public Network.

This nomenclature is not chosen from the user perspective, but from the security point of view. That is, a *Public Network* is a network that needs a lot more protection. You use this type of network when connecting to Airports networks, or the many wireless access points out there. A Private Network (Work and Home) is a network where trust among computers is higher. Incidentally, the difference between these two is that computers under a Home Network configuration can only access other members of this network. Whereas on a Work Network, it is possible to do more including taking server roles.

In addition to core network configuration under Windows 7, Windows Firewall also works in conjunction with the chosen network by enabling or disabling access features. For instance, under a Public Network, Windows Firewall doesn't enable Network Discovery.

Comment: Wow, this completely misses the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to map a local folder to a drive in My computer, you should use the **subst** command. There is also a GUI application for managing your virtual drives called [Visual Subst](http://www.ntwind.com/software/utilities/visual-subst.html).

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same problem during the creation of Excel file from Access Database. 
I solved the problem in this way:
In Control Panel I completed the MS Access Installation from Microsoft Office Plus 2010 set up. 
There was some Access add-on not installed.
Regards
Davide

Comment: For what question did you provide your answer? What has Excel to do with networks? Please edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I've had this before when setting a mapped drive on a different subnet on a different domain. I went through all the trusted zone stuff.

I landed up having to put an entry in the hosts file so Windows 7 could resolve the IP to a name, after that Office Trust Centre allowed it