# Make a network trusted on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, trust

Here is a possible dupe but I had no success with any of the answers.
[How do I tell Windows 7 to trust a particular network location?](https://superuser.com/questions/44503/how-do-i-tell-windows-7-to-trust-a-particular-network-location)

I can connect to a network via samba with no problem. However when I double click apps I get a warning untrusted message. Its pretty annoying since I always use the network. How do I tell windows I can trust it? There are also other side effects I notice but they may be app specific.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the untrusted message you get.

Comment: On the left, opening an exe. The right the dialog happens when i right click a zip file http://i.imgur.com/GvLeT.png

Comment: This has been previously asked [here](http://superuser.com/questions/149056/disable-these-files-might-be-harmful-to-your-computer-warning)